# What is mechanize.CookieJar() in mechanize Python?

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize-python

I've recently been working on a script that accesses a website's form to log in. Tried with requests but it seems that mechanize works better for this application. Was asking around and I wrote this code which does work:

```py
mCookieJar = mechanize.CookieJar()
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Manjaro; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1)')]
br.set_cookiejar(mCookieJar)
br.open(LoginUrl)
br.select_form(action="/takelogin.php")
br['email'] = Username
br['password'] = Password
resp = br.submit()
```

This works fine, but it creates a new session cookie every time the script is run. This is not ideal as in my user preferences for this website, I end up with a HUGE list of sessions that I need to manually close. The website does have another way around this for automated scripts - you can generate a permanent cookie just for this purpose.

However, I have no idea *what* mechanize.CookieJar() is. I can't find any mention of this method or class in the [Python mechanize documentation](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). There are a couple different cookiejar libs out there, but I don't need to include any of them for this to work.

So what is this class? Is it part of mechanize? How can I manually add cookies to it? There are some set_cookie() methods for the mechanize.Browser() class but I have no idea if these automatically add them to the active cookiejar. It seems very strange to me that this code works, and there are examples online using mechanize.CookieJar(), yet there is no mention of this anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Browsing through the [source](https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize/tree/master/mechanize) it seems like `mechanize` is re-exporting `CookieJar` from either `cookielib` (Python2) or `http.cookiejar` (Python3).

Having that said, if you want to persist your cookie across different runs of the script you should probably be using `FileCookieJar` instead. This also gets re-exported the same way:

- [`cookielib.FileCookieJar`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.FileCookieJar) (Python2)
- [`http.cookiejar.FileCookieJar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookiejar.html#http.cookiejar.FileCookieJar) (Python3)

Comment: Well, I'm going to be using a static cookie, so I don't need to worry about saving it to a file. But it's good to know it's just using http.cookiejar.

Comment: The normal `CookiJar` gets subclassed in `mechanize` though. Don't know in which ways this will change the behaviour: https://github.com/python-mechanize/mechanize/blob/7f13c0a701cfd89a80769f98af82d82cb95e9eaa/mechanize/_clientcookie.py#L52

Comment: http.cookiejar originated in mechanize (and ClientCookie before that).  Then it was contributed to Python as module cookielib.  In Python 3, cookielib was renamed to http.cookiejar.  Presumably, subsequently mechanize was changed to import that code from the python standard library.  urllib (if you configure it appropriately), mechanize.Browser and requests all use a cookiejar automatically, and you're not expected to call set_cookie yourself - unless you're manually hacking around the code not matching what browsers do exactly.